# How to access field from ManyToMany relation on top of Foreign key relation in a django serializer?

Tags: django, django-models, django-serializer

I have the following structure:

```
class Model_1():
    model_2_ref = models.ForeignKey(to="Model_2", null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    model_1_field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    ...

class Model_2():
    model_2_field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    model_2_field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    ....

class Model_3():
    model_2_ref = models.ManyToManyField(to="Model_2", related_name="model_2_rel_name")
    model_3_field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    user_id = models.Integer()
    ....
```

Each record of Model_1 is related to only one record of Model_2. Also each record of the Model_2 is related to only one record of Model_3 for the current user. The serializer will be used by a viewset that filters the matches from model_3 by user_id, transforming this into a One-to-one relation of sorts.

I have a serializer for Model_1, where I would like to include it's related fields from Model_2 and Model_3.

In theory, this is what I would like to achieve:

```
class Model_1_Serializer():
    model_1_field_1 = serializers.CharField()
    model_2_field_1 = serializers.CharField(source='model_2_ref.model_2_field_1')
    model_2_field_2 = serializers.CharField(source='model_2_ref.model_2_field_1')
    model_3_field_1 = serializers.CharField(source='model_2_ref.model_3_ref.model_3_field_1')
```

For model_3_field_1 this syntax does not work, but for the fields of model 2 it does. How can I access the related fields of Model_3 from the serializer of Model_1?

Comment: Why would it work, you can have multiple model3 instances as  you have Many-to-Many relationship in between https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Comment: @iklinac While I agree that the syntax doesn't look alright, each record of Model 1 has only one matching record from Model 3. I would like to fetch that value, and can't find any way to do it. This code above was not the only one I tried, tbh I don't even remember all of them. But I don't know how to access the related value of Model 3 from the serializer of Model 1.

Comment: It is not about syntax but about wrong relationship type, if you intend to always have only one item your relation is drastically off

Comment: @iklinac Although it is and should be a many-to-many relationship, due to a filter that is applied, each record from Model1 belongs to only one record from Model3 witin the context of the Viewset that uses this serializer. There is a user_id field in Model3 which ensures this limitation. I can't change the model structure, and I understand what you are saying. However, the bottom line is that I would still want to achieve the goal in the post with the models in the post. Also will update question to include this clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like (untested)?

**models.py**

```
class Model2(...):
    
    # this method returns the first model_3 instance or None:
    @property
    def model_3_single_ref(self): return self.model_3_ref.first() 


class Model3(...):
    
    model_3_field_1 = models.CharField(...)
    model_2_ref = models.ForeignKey(..., related_name = 'model_3_ref')
```

**serializers.py**

```
class Model_1_Serializer(...):

    # list of model_3_field_1s
    model_3_field_1s = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many = True,
        read_only = True,
        slug_field = 'model_3_field_1',
        source = 'model_2_ref.model_3_ref'
    )
    
    # model_3_field_1 as just a string:
    model_3_field_1 = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only = True,
        slug_field = 'model_3_field_1',
        source = 'model_2_ref.model_3_single_ref'            
    )
```

Comment: I read the documentation for SlugRelatedField, your solution makes sense. Unfortunately I can't test it in the code atm (will do so in a couple of hours). I was wondering if the field model_3_field_1s will be a flat field or a list. Despite the many-to-many relation between model 2 and model 3, I am certain that each row from model2 is related to only one row in model3. Therefore, each row from model1 will only have 1 value from model3. So even if the result was returned as a list (which I don't want to happen), it would be an array with only one element. Can I set many=False to achieve this?

Comment: Short answer - yes. Long answer - I'm not sure about the exact behavior of setting many to `False` - it may just work. Otherwise, if you have a `ManyToMany` / `ForeignKey` reference that only ever has a one-to-one relation you can do something like this (see edited answer).